# Conceptual doubts regarding the Emission Spectrum

Tags: nuclear-physics

I was reading up on the emission spectra and the author of my textbook states that

> If you expose a container of gas at low pressure to a strong electric field, light is emitted from the gas.

Now I have two questions:

1) Why is a low pressure gas used?

2) Does the strong elctric field cause the atoms to jump from the existing states to higher states or is it the photons?

From what I have gathered so far is that the atom will emit light if it falls to a lower energy level.But what excited the atom in the first place? Moreover, how should one imagine this? I have seen the diagrams showing the energy levels, but surely that is purely imaginary. Are the energy levels as real as the shells of an atom or what are they? I am sorry if my writing is a bit garbled, but I have been trying to understand this concept for a long time. Any insights or answers will be much appreciated.

Thank You...

Comment: It is quite likely that there is a nice fluorescent bulb somewhere near you that is happily emitting light. As for why low pressure, the Paschen curve is what you want to look into.

Comment: Yes, the energy levels are just as real (actually even more so) as the shells.  They are the eigenvalues that you get from solving Schrodinger's differential equation for the atom ($H\psi=E\psi$, where H is the sum of a second order differential operator and a potential, and \psi is the wave function).  They are indeed real numbers (in both a mathematical and philosophical sense) unlike the Schrodinger wave function which may be a complex number and has to be multiplied by its complex conjugate to yield a geometrical image of the shell.

Answer (score 0):

When a high voltage is applied, some electrons that are floating around will accelerate and gain energy. They will collide with other bound electrons and excite them. Sometimes, an electron can ionize multiple atoms if it has time to get accelerated sufficiently, creating more free electrons, leading to a shower of accelerating/energetic electrons. However, the bound electrons that just got excited, will emit photons when they jump to lower states. The reason the pressure needs to be low is that the free electrons need to have enough free path to accelerate to kick other electrons to get the process going. A short mean free path will not lead to such a process. In macroscopic terms, the gas pressure needs to be low, but not too low that collision rate vanishes.